# Why does MILITARY MEDAL emoji overlap with text when printed?

Tags: python, unicode, terminal, emoji

I am trying to print the [MILITARY MEDAL](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f396/index.htm) emoji (U+1F396) in Python using `print("[\U0001F396]")` and get the following output in iTerm2 on macOS:

[image]

and Terminal:

[image]

Why does  overlap with the `]` character?

Comment: This is an issue with the terminal emulator and does not regard Python.

Comment: It's Unicode-related and python is only used to repro. I added the terminal tag.

Comment: Yes, but the python tag is still misleading.

Comment: I think it's somewhat relevant because Python unlike many other languages provides good Unicode support. In some other languages you may not be able to print an emoji at all.

Comment: You can print out any characters you want to stdout in pretty much any language.

Comment: Also we don't know whether it's a bug in a terminal - it's a hypothesis. Feel free to post an answer with more details.

Comment: For example, it could be a bug in some Unicode processing library used in Python which is unlikely but would explain why the behavior occurs in two different terminals.

Comment: The terminal uses monospace fonts, while emojis are not primarily designed to look good in a monospace environment. The concepts *monospace* and *good-looking glyph kerning* are kind of mutually exclusive.

Comment: What lenz said.